# 要素のクリックに反応して別の要素を出現させる（JavaScriptによらない）方法

Tags: html, css

下記のサイトがどう動いているのか不明です。
https://mem.ooo/

コードを見ても、GoogleAnalytics以外JavaScriptなどで動いているようには見受けられないですし、
どのような仕組みで画面が動的に変わっているのでしょうか。

稚拙な質問になりますが、ご回答いただけますと幸いです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 「画面が動的に変わっている」 ってどの部分ですか？ Chromeで見てみましたが特別動的な動作はしないように見えます。

Comment: 私もChromeですが真ん中のアイコンをクリックすると画面が切り替わる？状態になります。

Comment: この部分です。 http://2.gigafile.nu/0828-f69f7616da6dec842f544258641b72c03

Comment: それってＣＳＳつまりスタイルによるものですね。ソースを見たならその部分のＨＴＭＬが同じページにあります。

Comment: 基本的に[このサイト](http://qiita.com/ryo620/items/a7941774469a6229a64a) で説明されているテクニックと同じです。

Comment: Alisaさん、無事疑問が解決されたようなので、回答の左にあるチェックマークをクリックしていただけませんか？そうすることで解決済みという目印になりますし、回答した方にポイントが与えられるのでお礼にもなります。

Answer (score 2):

上部の3アイコンをクリックするとそれぞれのコンテンツが表示される動作のことをいっているのでしょうか。(ご質問にはリンクだけでなく、できるだけ詳細に対象となる動作を記述してください。リンク切れなどがあると、全く質問が意味をなさなくなってしまいます。)

隠しチェックボックスを作り、その直後に表示したい要素を配置して、チェックボックスの`checked`状態によって、その要素の表示スタイルを変更しています。アイコンやクローズボタンは隠しチェックボックスへの`label`にしてあるため、チェックボックスそのものは隠されていても、そのチェック状態を変更できるという仕掛けです。

擬似セレクタを含むCSSのセレクタ記述が理解できていれば、(後はネタがわかれば)理解できるコードだと思います。

最初は元サイトのコードを全部引用して説明を書こうと思ったのですが、公開サイトのコードの一部とはいえ、ライセンスが不明確なコードをむやみに引用するべきではないので、簡略化したコードを作ってみました。

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
  .hidden-content {
    display: none;
  }
  .content-switch:checked + .hidden-content {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
  }
  /*
  .content-switch {
    position : absolute ;
    top : -9999px ;
    left : -9999px ;
    width : 1px ;
    height : 1px ;
  }
  */
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <label for="hidden-content-switch">Open</label>
  </div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="hidden-content-switch" class="content-switch">
  <div class="hidden-content">
    This content is hidden by default.<br>
    <label for="hidden-content-switch">Close</label>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS内でチェックボックスを非表示にする部分をコメントアウトしてあるので、どんな動作になっているのかわかっていただけるかと思います。丸ごとコピーして.htmlファイルを作成してご確認ください。

Comment: スニペットにしておけばローカルでhtmlファイルを作らなくても解答欄内で直接見れるようにできてわかりやすいと思いますよ。エディタで左から7つ目のボタンです（画像挿入の右側）。

Comment: すごく、わかりやすかったです！ありがとうございますm(_ _)m

Comment: @packet0 さん、コメントありがとうございます。正直「よくわからなかったから使わなかった」と言うところなので、出来れば試してみるべきなんでしょうが、質問者さんのコメントもつきましたので、また次の機会にしようと思います。

Comment: @LePered'OO この質問を見るのは質問者の方だけではありません。もし同じ疑問を持った人がこの質問を見た際や、この質問をたまたま見かけて興味を持った人にもスニペット化されていている方が理解しやすいですよね。長らく利用されているのでわかりきっていることかもしれませんが、Q&Aサイトというものは質問者と回答者だけがプレーヤーではありません。(もっとも、この質問タイトルでたどり着くのは難しいかもしれませんが。)

Comment: @hinaloe さん、では正直に申し上げてしまうと「スニペット化されていてい‌​る方が理解しやすい」かどうかは甚だ疑問だと言うことです。スニペット化されている方が理解しやすいと思われるなら、あなた自身が「理解しやすい」回答を投稿できます。どうぞご自由にその機能をお使いください。

Comment: @LePered'OO さん、@hinaloeさん、 自分も編集で変えて良ければそのままでと1度は思ったのですが、本家meta（http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242353/is-it-recommended-to-convert-code-in-existing-posts-to-stack-snippets）の方で他の編集のついでならまだしも、スニペット化だけのための編集は新しい質問をトップから下ろすだけなのであまり推奨されないとあったので放置してました。会話を始めといてあれですが、コメント部を変えてみる必要もあるのでこの回答は今のままでいいかなと思います。

Comment: @packet0 さん、短い言葉で見方によってはすごく乱暴に見えるコメントに対して丁寧なご返答ありがとうございます。もう少し補足させてもらうと「よくわからなかったから使わなかった」と言うのは本当に正直なところで、さらにどの程度理解しやすいのか効果が不明なところで、あえて新しいことを覚えたくない、と言う後半の部分も正直な気持ちです。できれば時間をとって(編集ではなく別回答として)回答を投稿していただければ、読者の方の判定も仰げるのでその辺も参考になるかと思っております。質問者の人にも未来の読者にもより良い回答にすると言う方向性は共通だと思いますので、機会があれば、良い見本をお示しいただければ助かります。